# How do I filter the differences out of three arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have three arrays each having SimpleXML Objects in them. They are structured like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [post_id] => 1476
            [name] => Johnson Fisheries Ltd.
            [owner] => Mr. John Johnson
        )
)
```

I want to be able to compare all 3 arrays and filter out the differences so that the results have only the elements that are the same in all 3 arrays.

For example:

```
Array1
    (
        [0] => 1476
        [1] => 1560
        [2] => 1342
    )

Array2
    (
        [0] => 2454
        [1] => 1476
    )

Array3
    (
        [0] => 3412
        [1] => 7512
        [2] => 2454
        [4] => 1476
    )
```

The resulting array would only contain [0] => 1476

What's the best way to do this? I've looked for a function that will compare arrays in this way but I have had no luck. Any ideas?

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over your first array, checking it against the 2nd and 3rd using [in_array](http://php.net/in_array), like this:

```
foreach($array1 as $post_id) {
    if(in_array($post_id, $array2) && in_array($post_id, $array3)) {
        // We have a winner!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Best option will be using php's built-in [array-intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function.

```
$answer =  array_intersect($Array1,$Array2,$Array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new array.

add all elements of the first array into the new array.

iterate through all the other elements, find out which elements in your new array are in the array to be compared. remove all the elements that don't appear.

at the end of your iterations, you have your desired array.